# Is an dispatcher xml created for every package in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was going through spring tutorials I came to the doubt about the dispatcher xml feature of spring, I'm not sure if this is a valid doubt, I was not able to find anything regarding this. I wrote a dispatcher xml based on the tutorial in "tutorials point" the dispatcher xml is given below

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.o rg/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="Student" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

My doubt is on a particular line in the dispatcher xml the line is given below

```
<context:component-scan base-package="Student" />
```

If base package has to be specified in every dispatcher xml should I create a new dispatcher xml for every package I create or place all my packages as sub-package to a main package, what is the development standard here, what is usually done?

My web.xml is given below.

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>SpringStud</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>SpringStud</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It seems you don't really understand what a servlet is. What you posted is an XML configuration for Spring MVC. It's not a servlet. A servlet is a Java class, not related to Spring at all, which extends HttpServlet. Given that your terminology is all wrong, I can't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry I used the term servlet because the name of these xml files are suffixed with "-servlet" and these files are called in web.xml in the same manner as servlets in j2ee. I have changed the term to dispatcher xml. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Is `Student` really the name of the package? Either way, the component scanning will recursively inspect all lower level packages (starting from Student - if that is even a package name). You can also use comma separated packages for the value i.e. `base-package="com.mypackage,com.myotherpackage"`

Comment: The xml file is the configuration file for one DispatcherServlet instance declared in the web.xml. A typical webapp uses only one such instance, so why would you need more than one xml file to configure it?

Comment: @JB Nizet I was able to use two such xml files, the default one was   dispatcher-servlet.xml, it had all the initial configuration, and I created one like SpringStud-servlet.xml. I used both in my web.xml file both worked fine and I did not know you could use different base-packages as peeskillet mentioned in his comment. I have also added my web.xml in the question